# Create codeigniter session table automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

How can I create codeigniter session table automatically?
When I use creator function in my controller constructor and when the session table not exist I see codeigniter error. My code is:

```
function admin() { 
parent::__construct();
ob_start();
if(!$this->db->table_exists('session'))//for `first time` run.
    $this->utilmodel->create_session_table(); //this function create session table with CI structure
ob_end_clean();
$this->load->library('session'); 
... 
}
```

My obviously error is:

```
Error Number: 1146    
Table 'dbs.session' doesn't exist

INSERT INTO `session` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`,
`last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES
('0a78608576684ebc2c0050b8f4810f', '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla/5.0
(Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.21', 1001550875, '')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\folder\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I know exactly after

```
parent::__construct()
```

my error happens.

Comment: Need more insight into your code. I am also not sure why you are trying to create the table on the fly. You are best to work with a database migration script instead of creating tables on the fly.

Comment: yes, you need to use hooks. to be more specific `pre_system` will work.

Comment: i should create on the fly table because of my system features. it have a configuration panel that config base system settings and etc.

Comment: Yes you right, i do not think about hooks before. if my problem solved i will say here. anyway thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

just go to in your phpmyadmin and run this sql query then use session. you have to create ci_session table in your database to use session in codeigniter

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: i see but i have a creator function that do this but before running of this function codeigniter generate this error, i dont want create this table manually by phpmyadmin.

Comment: if you are using session_start() then don't use it before creating session table because you can't use it without session table in CI.

Comment: maybe session_start() function used in codeigniter constructor, if yes so where i can change codeigniter constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You should use hook `pre_controller` BUT there is one problem: CodeIgniter does not allow to use DB class in `pre_system` and `pre_controller` hooks, so you can not install session table using active record ( `$this->db->query()` ).

I know that CodeIgniter guide says

> pre_controller - 
>   Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. **All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done**.

but this is **NOT** true... (you can read about it on other posts: [pre_controller hook does not load base classes like docs state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805828/pre-controller-hook-does-not-load-base-classes-like-docs-state)).

Anyway, you can connect to your database manually. This is a little dirty solution, but I don't know better one.

Here is my code to install session table automatically.

```
<?php

class SessionTableInstaller
{
    public function install() 
    {
        if( $db_config = $this->getDBConfig() ) {

            $db_handle = mysql_connect($db_config['hostname'], $db_config['username'], $db_config['password']);

            if ($db_handle === FALSE) {
                throw new Exception('Cannot connect with MySql server');
            }

            if (mysql_select_db($db_config['database'], $db_handle) === FALSE) {
                throw new Exception('Cannot select database');
            }

            $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
                session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
                ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
                user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
                last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                user_data text NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (session_id) ,
                KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB default CHARSET=utf8 ;";

            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close($db_handle);
        }
    }

    private function getDBConfig()
    {
        require __DIR__ . '/../config/database.php';

        if(!isset($db) || !isset($active_group)) {
            return false;
        }

        $db_config = $db[ $active_group ];
        return $db_config;
    }
}

/* End of file sessionTable.php */
/* Location: ./application/hooks/sessionTable.php */
```

And here is code in **config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class'    => 'SessionTableInstaller',
    'function' => 'install',
    'filename' => 'sessionTable.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```